# Compare multiple Slopes between conditions

Tags: regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am working with data extracted from Electroencephalography (EEG) studies done to 10 subjects and related behavioural data. In the next plot I show the relation between behavioural data (x axis) and EEG measures (y axis) from 8 different channels (electrodes). The left plot is for channels located in the left hemisphere and the right plot is for electrodes located in the right hemisphere.

[image]

First of all, I want to compare if there is an hemisphere effect, meaning that the slopes for the left electrodes are steeper than the slopes for the right electrodes (as I suspect from the plot). Take in mind that all electrodes are registered in each subject at the same time (repeated measures for channels) and I have 10 subjects. The behavioural measure is only one per subject.

I was trying with a linear-mixed-model with this formula. I compare two models, with and without interaction:

```
model.Full = 
lme(EEGmeasure~behavMeasure*hemisphere,random= 
~1|subjectID,data=dataEEGbehav)
summary(model.Full)

model.Null = 
lme(EEGmeasure~behavMeasure+hemisphere,random= 
~1|subjectID,data=dataEEGbehav)
summary(model.Null)

anova(update(model.Full, . ~ ., method = "ML"),update(model.Null, . ~ 
.,method = "ML"))
```

What do you think about this approach? Do you know any better way?
Am I modelling different intercepts and different slopes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good approach. Last question is not clear. behaveMeasure's slope? Different slope between two models or between hemispheres?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking about random effects of slopes and intercepts, because I could have differente intercept in each channel. I wonder if I am considering those differences in the model.